# Calculating probability of 1 player winning in A vs B vs C vs D....

Tags: probability

I've done a tonne of searching to try and find out what this type of problem might be called, or to find a similar example, but the few examples I've found the comments always get caught up in edge case scenarios that don't apply.

I'm not sure if my caluclation is actually really simple, or should be more complex. Just after a bit of guidance..

The scenario:

- 4 players in a game where it is "free for all". Only 1 winner. No draws.
- I know the pairwise probability of A beating B, A beating C, A beating D, B beating C etc.

Is it possible to work out the probability that A will win? If so, what does the math look like?

At the moment I believe it is just P(AB) * P(AC) * P(AD), but I'm not sure?

Comment: More information about the game is needed.  You are assuming that the events that A beats B, A beats C, and A beats D are independent, but for many games, that isn't so.  Suppose the game is to throw a dart nearer to the center of a dartboard.  If A beats B, he has presumably made a good throw, which makes it more likely that he beats C also.

Comment: When you have a multiplayer game there are often opportunities for players to collaborate, so head-to-head results are even less useful than you would think.  A two person game is completely different because there are no alliances.  It is hard to say it is hopeless without more definition of the game, but it probably is.

Comment: If you ignore the specifics & physics of the game (such as collaboration between players), lets assume it is a simulation I have made, 4 computer controlled players against each other. And I have worked out that player A beats player B 65% of the time. Player A beats player C 35% of the time. Etc. Is there a way to work out a theoretical probability that player A would beat all the others?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C,D$ be the random variables representing the degree to which each player wins.  So the event of player-A beating player-B is denoted: $A{>}B$ and so forth.

You *do not have the distributions for these random variables*. You merely have the probabilities for their pairwise comparisons: $\mathsf P(A{>}B), \mathsf P(A{>}C), \mathsf P(A{>}D), \mathsf P(B{>}C)$, et cetera.   You would like to use these to determine probabilities for multiple comparisons, like $\mathsf P(A{>}B{>}C)$, and such.

Well, we can see that:

$$\mathsf P(A{>}B, A{>}C)=\mathsf P(A{>}B{>}C)+\mathsf P(A{>}C{>}B)$$

This raises two issues.

- The events of $A{>}B$ and of $A{>}C$ are not going to be independent, as both events are determined by how well player-A does in the free-for-all.
- The events of $A{>}B{>}C$ and $A{>}C{>}B$ are not guaranteed to be of equal measure.

So, there is *no way* to evaluate these probabilities without access to the actual distributions of the random variables (that is their *joint* distributions).   The probabilities that you do have are insufficient.

Comment: If I do have access to the actual distributions, what am I then able to do with that information?